how to connect mysql database data to echart
I tried create a web based data visualization in farm pond water quality monitoring. So, insert water quality sensor data to MySQL database . This data comes from the sensor to db every 5 minutes.
I wanted to visualize these data to a large scale area chart. I tried to get data from MySQL by using a php file. But don't understand how that data feed to graph generation in Real Time a basic,
Please help. Example code in echart website I download and try to modify it as I require.
<script type="text/javascript">
    
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

let base = +new Date(1968, 9, 3);
let oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
let date = [];

let data = [Math.random() * 300];

for (let i = 1; i < 20000; i++) {
  var now = new Date((base += oneDay));
  date.push([now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()].join('/'));
  data.push(Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + data[i - 1]));
}

option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    position: function (pt) {
      return [pt[0], '10%'];
    }
  },
  title: {
    left: 'center',
    text: 'Large Area Chart'
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      dataZoom: {
        yAxisIndex: 'none'
      },
      restore: {},
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: date
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    boundaryGap: [0, '100%']
  },
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      start: 0,
      end: 10
    },
    {
      start: 0,
      end: 10
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Fake Data',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      sampling: 'lttb',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
      },
      areaStyle: {
        color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
          {
            offset: 0,
            color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
          }
        ])
      },
      data: data
    }
  ]
};



if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);

  </script>


If you need real time updated chart, then your technology stack is not adequate as mysql cannot stream data to a client. You need something like kafka to do the data streaming for you. You can still use mysql as an analytical data store for queries that do not require real time updates.

Thank you. I will try to learn working with Kafka. Is it difficult to learn and work Kafka ? because I do not have good programing knowledge.

I'm sorry, but I can't tell you how easy or difficult it will be for you to learn a new piece of technology.
